# Where in Torah the change of Muslims' Qibla is mentioned?

Tags: jews, qiblah, torah

In surah Baqara, aya 144 Allah (SWT) says:

قَدْ نَرَىٰ تَقَلُّبَ وَجْهِكَ فِى ٱلسَّمَآءِ ۖ فَلَنُوَلِّيَنَّكَ قِبْلَةًۭ تَرْضَىٰهَا ۚ فَوَلِّ وَجْهَكَ شَطْرَ ٱلْمَسْجِدِ ٱلْحَرَامِ ۚ وَحَيْثُ مَا كُنتُمْ فَوَلُّوا۟ وُجُوهَكُمْ شَطْرَهُۥ ۗ وَإِنَّ ٱلَّذِينَ أُوتُوا۟ ٱلْكِتَـٰبَ لَيَعْلَمُونَ أَنَّهُ ٱلْحَقُّ مِن رَّبِّهِمْ ۗ وَمَا ٱللَّهُ بِغَـٰفِلٍ عَمَّا يَعْمَلُونَ ١٤٤

> We have seen your face turned towards the heaven. So We will turn you towards a direction that will satisfy you. So turn your face towards the Sacred Mosque. And wherever you may be, turn your faces towards it. Those who were given the Book know that it is the Truth from their Lord; and God is not unaware of what they do.

And in [this](https://abdurrahman.org/2014/01/27/changingqiblah/) article it is mentioned that Jews knew that Muslims would change their Qibla.

How would they know? Where in the Torah, or Tanakh it has been mentioned?

Comment: Why do you think that qibla change be explicitly mentioned anywhere else than the qur'an? What is clear is that the people of the book would know that their teachings will be abrogated by Islam.

Answer (score 2):

It is not mentioned explicitly in the Torah or Tanakh today or at the time of Ibn Kathir's tafsir (which is what your article is).

He only means the Jews of Madinah had writings with them that indicated to that. If those existed or his interpretation is correct, they do not survive in the public Torah or Tanakh we have available today.

I think a plainer interpretation is to simply say what the verse explicitly says:

> Those who were given the book know it is the truth from their Lord.

The verse does not say they know because it is in their books that the qiblah would be changed. They know it is true because they know the Prophet Muhammad (SAW) is true after they have seen all his signs and qualities that match their knowledge of prophets in the Torah.

Allah says two verses later:

> Those to whom We gave the Scripture know him as they know their own sons. But indeed, a party of them conceal the truth while they know [it]. (2:146)

Answer (score 0):

It cannot be expected that it is written in the Torah because even the redaction of the present Tora has been finished more than 1000 earlier, and it is not written there. It's not part of any oral tradition.

The only passage in the written Torah that points to Muhammad (p.b.u.h) is the promise to Ishmael and Hagar that a great people would arise from him. We have no knowledge of the prophecies of the ancient prophets except what has been related in the writings that are preserved and, that is the point, what has been revealed in the Quran.

And the Quran doesn't state that their knowledge comes from the Torah, rather they also received the Quran. The change of the Qibla forced them to show whether or not they accept the new revelation.